# How to fix inconvertible types in Android Studio

Tags: google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to start an application based on google maps in Android Studio. I followed the instructions and started an Google Maps activity.

Then I created according to the instructions an API key and enabled the `maps SDK android for android` and copied the key into the app.

but then when I'm trying to run the app (didnt change a thing) I get this error:

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'
```

for this line of code:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
and this error: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:5-42:19 to override.
in the event.
```

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.android.myfirstmap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
```

I looked around to see if there is a solution that fixes also my problem but none of what I tried was the right one.

does anyone knows how to fix it? evreything is updated.

Comment: Please post your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I posted it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Support Map Fragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment) extends `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`.

You are importing `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` which uses `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. These are two different classes so they are incompatible.

You need to migrate your app to Android X: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Then, in your `build.gradle` file, replace `com.android.support:support-fragment` with `androidx.fragment:fragment`.

Hope that helps!